# merge columns with NA values

Tags: r, merge

Is there a way to merge columes with NA values?

for example

```
a <- data.frame(x1 = c("a", NA, NA), y1 = c(NA, "e1", NA), z1 = c("g", NA, "i"), x2 = c(NA, "b", NA), y2 = c("d", "e2", "f"), z2 = c(NA, "h", NA), x3 = c(NA, NA, "c"))
```

gives

```
    x1   y1   z1   x2 y2   z2   x3
1    a <NA>    g <NA>  d <NA> <NA>
2 <NA>   e1 <NA>    b e2    h <NA>
3 <NA> <NA>    i <NA>  f <NA>    c
```

the desired output is

```
     x       y    z
1    a       d    g
2    b   e1 e2    h
3    c       f    i
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `is.na` and `ifelse` to transform `NA` to empty strings, then merge columns with `paste`, using `trimws` to remove leading and trailing spaces:

```
a <- data.frame(x1 = c("a", NA, NA), y1 = c(NA, "e1", NA), z1 = c("g", NA, "i"), x2 = c(NA, "b", NA), y2 = c("d", "e2", "f"), z2 = c(NA, "h", NA), x3 = c(NA, NA, "c"), 
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
a2 <- lapply(a, function(x) ifelse(is.na(x),"",x))
data.frame(x=trimws(paste(a2$x1,a2$x2,a2$x3)),
                 y=trimws(paste(a2$y1,a2$y2)), 
                 z=trimws(paste(a2$z1,a2$z2)))
  x     y z
1 a     d g
2 b e1 e2 h
3 c     f i
```

Comment: Works out perfectly. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way using `dplyr` and `reshape2`:

```
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)
melt(as.matrix(a)) %>%
  filter(!is.na(value)) %>%
  group_by(Var1, g=substr(Var2, 1, 1)) %>%
  summarise(value=paste(value, collapse=" ")) %>%
  dcast(Var1 ~ g, value.var="value") %>%
  select(-Var1)
```